# Построение графиков/диаграмм по данным из xml на C#

Tags: c#, xml

Нужно в chart control построить диаграммы/графики по данным из xml типа:

```
<doc>
<id>...</id>
<date1>...</date1>
<date2>...</date2>
<data count="6">
<row>
  <denial>...</denial>
  <date>...</date>
  <visits>...</visits>
  <visitors>...</visitors>
  <depth>...</depth>
  <page_views>...</page_views>
  <visit_time>...</visit_time>
  <new_visitors>...</new_visitors>
  <id>...</id>
</row>
<row>
  <denial>...</denial>
  <date>...</date>
  <visits>...</visits>
  <visitors>...</visitors>
  <depth>...</depth>
  <page_views>...</page_views>
  <visit_time>...</visit_time>
  <new_visitors>...</new_visitors>
  <id>...</id>
</row>
...
</doc>
```

Обычно для чтения xml использую код наподобие:

```
foreach(XmlNode node in xmlNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            switch (node.Name)
            {
                case "name1":
                    label1.Text = node.InnerText;
                    break;
                case "name2":
                    label2.Text = node.InnerText;
                    break;
...
```

Никак не могу понять как нужно данные из xml использовать для

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(x, y);
```

где, например, x - `<date>`, а y - `<visits>`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это можно реализовать

Comment: примерно так: `foreach(var p in rows.Select(row => new { X=int.Parse(row.Element("date").Value), Y=int.Parse(row.Element("visits").Value) })) { chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(p.X, p.Y); }`

Comment: @Stack, спасибо

Comment: @Stack, можете, пожалуйста, пояснить чем должно быть "row" и в каком контексте использовать код?

Comment: могу. чуть позже напишу ответ и пример на c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// #r "System.Xml.Linq"
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

var xml = @"<data>  
              <row>
                <date>1.27.2016</date>
                <visitors>12345</visitors>
              </row>
              <row>
                <date>1.28.2016</date>
                <visitors>54321</visitors>
              </row>
            </data>";
var rows = XElement
           .Parse(xml)      // или .Load(uri);
           .Elements("row")
           .Select(row => 
              new {
                 Date = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Element("date").Value, "m.dd.yyyy", null),
                 Visitors = int.Parse(row.Element("visitors").Value)
                 });
foreach (var r in rows)
    Console.WriteLine(r.Date + "; " + r.Visitors);
```

Результат

```
1/27/2016 12:01:00 AM; 12345
1/28/2016 12:01:00 AM; 54321
```